# Using moment.js (or moment-timezone.js) in TypeScript project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, momentjs

This is what I've done so far :

- Install NodeJs and play with it : the `node` command is available
- Install TypeScript using `npm` : `npm install typescript -g`
- Now I am able to create `.ts` files, use the TypeScript syntax and compile the files using `tsc` command

Okay, from now on everything works fine. What I am doing is translating a Java library to TypeScript. But I am facing an issue : The Java library is using the `Calendar` object and I need the same kind of object in TypeScript.

I've searched a bit and found [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). I wanted to import that library into my TypeScript files.

Question : How do I do that ? I've looked around on StackOverflow but in every post I found there was something that made me think this would not be my solution, like :

- Install `typings` / `tsd` : I've read that now `moment.js` has now a definition file (? sorry, maybe it is not the good term, but it has a `moment.d.ts` file)
- Check in `random.config.json` file : I do not have such a configuration file (not in NodeJs in my guess, and in TypeScript I have the `tsconfig.json` file, and tried to include the `moment.d.ts` file but I wasn't able to import it in TypeScript > `"cannot find module moment"`)
- Install moment from `npm` : I've done it, but I didn't find out how to include the `moment.d.ts` file in my project.

and so on ...

I would like to know what I am missing and how to include `moment` in my `.ts` files in order to use it. I probably lack of some knowledge about the organisation of these modules, so every explanation will be welcome.

- NodeJs version : 7.1.0
- TypeScript version : 2.0.10

**EDIT**

After digging a bit, I found that I could compile my `.ts` files using `tsc Test.ts --traceResolution` to see if the imports are resolved correctly. Result : They are ! The real problem now is that my IDE (Visual Studio) doesn't know about `moment`.

[image]

The thing is that I have created each `.ts` file manually, by creating a new file, changing the extension and opening it in Visual Studio. Maybe that is the problem ? I'm just using Visual Studio as a text editor with IntelliSense. Do I have to make something in order to make Visual Studio understand that the import comes from NodeJS ?

Comment: There is a section on how to use moment in typescript in the docs on [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: This is what I did, but as stated, when I want to import `moment` I got an error `cannot find module "moment"`. I also tried to set the compiler options but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not have to install moment.js interface because it provides its own types definitions.
2. Import moment.js in typescript (**you were right**).

   import * as moment from 'moment';
3. Use moment.js in typescript

   var momentObject: moment.Moment

   momentObject.something() (ex: momentObject.add(..))

Comment: I finally was able to use moment.js in my solution but I had to do some changes. Every class I had I put them into a single `namespace`, but then I was unable to import `moment`. I had to change `namespace MyNamespace { export class MyClass { ... }}` to `export class MyClass { ...}` only. Do you know why ? I will then let you write an answer that I will gladly accept, thank you